# C++ partial template specialization issue with gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, template-meta-programming

I am trying to calculate GCD, at compile time using template partial specialization.
Following code works fine with clang3.8 but not with gcc7.1. With GCC, it's going into recursive template instantiation without realizing terminating case.

```
template <int N, int M>                                                                                                                                              
struct GCD{                                                                                                                                                          
    static const int value = (N>M)? GCD<N%M, M>::value : GCD<N, M%N>::value;                                                                                         
};                                                                                                                                                                   

template <int M>                                                                                                                                                     
struct GCD<0, M>{                                                                                                                                                    
    static const int value = M;                                                                                                                                      
};                                                                                                                                                                   

template <int M>                                                                                                                                                     
struct GCD<M, 0>{                                                                                                                                                    
    static const int value = M;                                                                                                                                      
};                                                                                                                                                                   


int main()                                                                                                                                                           
{                                                                                                                                                                    
    static_assert(GCD<12,15>::value == 3, "Error");                                                                                                                          
}
```

Who is behaving sane here?

Comment: Perhaps only do a forward declaration of the two-argument `GCD` structure, with the definition below the specializations. Because at the time of the first definition the compiler doesn't really know about the two specializations. Which compiler is correct I don't know though.

Comment: Note that in C++17 there will be a [`gcd`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) function in the `<numeric>` header.

Comment: And your maths don't work here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve the problem, I propose the following improvement

```
template <int N, int M, bool = (M != 0) && (N != 0) && (N > M)>
struct GCD;

template <int N, int M>
struct GCD<N, M, true>
 { static constexpr int value { GCD<N%M, M>::value }; };

template <int N, int M>
struct GCD<N, M, false>
 { static constexpr int value { GCD<N, M%N>::value } ; };

template <int M>
struct GCD<0, M, false>
 { static constexpr int value { M }; };

template <int M>
struct GCD<M, 0, false>
 { static constexpr int value { M }; };
```

If you want to know if is right g++ or clang++, well... I don't know what, exactly, a compiler can or must do in this circumstances so... I don't know.

Precisely, I don't know, when `N > M` and a compiler encounter,

```
     static const int value = (N>M)? GCD<N%M, M>::value : GCD<N, M%N>::value;
```

if the compiler must (or can) implement only `GCD<N%M, M>` or if must (or can) implement `GCD<N, M%N>` also.

Anyway, if I'm not wrong, clang++ implement only `GCD<N%M, M>` where g++ implement both.

My improvement is tailored to avoid this problem.

Comment: You are right, gcc implements both. 
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81134